# Mutiple stages - Buttons don´t react?

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx, stage

once again a newbie needs an advice from you, gracious stranger.

I have some problems that, even after googling them, couldn´t been solved.

I have 2 Stages in my game with a Table in each one that hold Buttons:
The first one stores a Table with ingame buttons : move up/down and pause
the second one stores a Table that represents the pause menu.

if "pause" is clicked (the game pauses and) I want to draw the second stage that now can process input.

I initialized 2 stages:

```
public void create(){

...
mainStage = new Stage(viewport,batch);
menuStage = new Stage(viewport,batch);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mainStage);
...
```

the pause Button got an Listener that sets the (enum) STATE to PAUSE
(same for the "resume" Button in the pause menu, that sets the state to RUNNING)

```
pause.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        thisState = STATE.PAUSE;
        Gdx.input.setInputProzessor(menuStage);

        }
    });
```

then in the render method

```
switch (gameState) {
            case RUNNING:

                deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                stateTime += deltaTime; // for the animations

                Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
                Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

                update(deltaTime);

                batch.begin(); 
                ... draws the characters
                batch.end();

                mainStage.act(deltaTime);
                mainStage.draw();
                break;

            case PAUSE:
                Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.6f); I want the background to become slightly darker.
                Gdx.app.log("Game State","Game is PAUSED");
                menuStage.act(deltaTime);
                menuStage.draw();

        }
```

If I start the mainStage Buttons appear, but arent clickable.
What I have noticed is that the game stops if I click in the middle of the screen. Howeverm the "pause" Button´s Listener apparantly doesnt even react to that as there was no notfication on the console, that the game is paused, nor that the Button was clicked.

My Start Screen uses only one Stage and works perfectly with the same setup.

What I think the resons might be:

- I used setInputProcessor falsely
- I used Viewport falsely (and resize)
- I have to somehow let the first stage disappear before drawing a new stage

Help is appreciated a lot! Thank you.

---

*sry for my bad english*
*.. and for my formating (this is my first Post here)*

Comment: I don't see what's preventing your stage from getting proper input, but I do see a few bugs that you could fix. Might get you closer. First, you're not clearing the color buffer bit when in Pause state. Second, setting the clear color to have a lower alpha will not make it darker--nothing is darker than black. Third, you're only updating deltaTime and stateTime when in game mode, so these values will be "stuck" with the wrong values in pause mode.

Comment: Try ClickListener

Comment: @Tenfour04 thx alot, even tho it didn´t fix my issue at least some other potential errors have been eliminated... if it doesnt bother you to much could you suggest a better way to create a Pause window ingame?

Comment: @eldo ChangeListener usally works, at least in my StartScreen it worked fine but thx

Comment: I don't see a problem with your method, but it might be simpler to use a single stage. Add all your pause menu stuff to a Group instead of your Stage. Then add or remove that Group from the stage when switching game states.

Comment: You're forgetting to call break at the end your PAUSE case. That might be a part of the problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem: I had to put the setInPutProcessor in the show method of the screen as this wasnt my starting screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your code, gdx is only processing inputs for mainStage, you could swap input processors when showing the menu or use a input multiplexer like this:

```
public void create(){

[...]
mainStage = new Stage(viewport,batch);
menuStage = new Stage(viewport,batch);
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
multiplexer.addProcessor(mainStage);
multiplexer.addProcessor(menuStage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
[...]

}
```